# MrBayes outgroups

Tags: tree, sequence, bioinformatics, phylogeny

I am using MrBayes to construct a phylogenetic tree and was wondering how you could specify several sequences of the same species to be the "outgroup". I can only select one sequence as the outgroup, which makes for a strange tree.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If MrBayes is allowed to freely infer the topology of the tree, you have no guarantee that the species you believe form the outgroup will be grouped together. I guess that is why it doesn't really make sense to select several species as outgroup.

However, it may be possible to enforce topological constraints: See section 4.4 of the manual here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NBISweden/MrBayes/develop/doc/manual/Manual_MrBayes_v3.2.pdf

You could try forcing your putative ingroup to form a clade. Assuming your outgroup species are O1, O2 and O3 and your ingroup species are I1, I2, I3, I4 and I5, you might try something like that:

```
constraint ingroup = I1 I2 I3 I4 I5;
prset topologypr=constraints(ingroup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Under most configurations, MrBayes generates unrooted trees, which are only 'rooted' on an outgroup for the purposes of display.  Unless your model specifies the position of a root and attaches significance to that point, it would be valid to re-root the tree on the chosen multi-leaf outgroup when plotting it in external software.  In R you could accomplish this with

[TreeTools::RootTree](https://rdrr.io/cran/TreeTools/man/RootTree.html)(tree, c('tip1', 'tip2'))